# How do I integrate the function $\sqrt{(6x + 2)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you integrate $\sqrt{(6x + 2)}$?

I've tried to use the following substitutions: let $x = \sin(u)$ and $dx = \cos(u)$ (along the lines of the Yahoo Answers link). I tried looking for simple examples of integrals with square roots [on Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080130100928AAYKkoZ&guccounter=1) and elsewhere by Googling, but couldn't find any simpler ones, and that substitution got me nowhere.

Comment: Welcome to Math.Stackexchange! What approaches have to tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how to integrate $\sqrt{x}$?  Have you heard of "*u-substitution*"?

Comment: I don't know if my search engine is bad, but I just found out complicated examples. This is a simple one

Comment: Hi @bcloney - You need to provide some background/context to each question posted along with all methods you have tried so far (including the detail where applicable). If you are unable to begin, advise so in your question. Welcome to MSE btw!

Comment: Integrating $\sqrt x$ is basically the same as integrating any power:

$$\int x^n dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} + C$$

Keep in mind $\sqrt x = x^{1/2}$.

Comment: As for the downvoting, it has nothing to do with "big ego." MSE just hates problem-statement questions - where a person basically posts a question with no context, no explanation of what they understand/where they're stuck/their attempts and nothing else. Often comes off as someone just looking for someone to give them a solution to copy and paste into their homework.

Comment: @bcloney - Just to add to Eevee Trainer's comment re integral, please note it doesn't hold for $n = - 1$ in which $\int x^{-1} \:dx = \int \frac{1}{x}\:dx = \ln|x| + C$ where $C$ is the constant of integration.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Its not homework but I get it

Comment: The technique of "*u-substitution*" for integration is just the same thing as the technique of using the chain-rule for derivation in reverse.  Similarly, finding antiderivatives are essentially analogous to finding derivatives in reverse.  Even if it is your first week with integration, I would expect you to have some experience with derivatives and should have seen how to derive $x^{3/2}$.  If you know how to derive $x^{3/2}$ then you should be able to figure out how to integrate $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: @bcloney, Have you consulted a calculus book? If not, you can search for good references in google (there are several!). Also, there are numerous pdfs in which you can find examples like this solved.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have some experience with derivatives and antiderivatives, and I know even before posting the question that sqrt x is x^1/2 .  Really thanks for that "u-substitution" explanation, I've a good starting point with this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Make the $u$-substitution $u = 6x+2$.
- Don't forget that $\sqrt u = u^{1/2}$ and that, for all $n \neq -1$, we have

$$\int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C$$

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for:

$$\int(6x+2)^\frac12 dx$$

Notice that if we let $u=6x+2$, $\frac{du}{dx}=6$ which leads to $dx=\frac16 du$

In other words, the above integral is *exactly the same* as this:
$$\int (u)^\frac12 \cdot \frac 16 du$$
You can take the constant outside the integral to make this:
$$\frac 16 \int u^\frac 12 du$$

And deal with that integral using the normal power rules.

At the end, don't forget to resubsitute $u=6x+2$ back in!

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\sqrt{6x+2}\operatorname dx=\frac16\cdot\frac23(6x+2)^{\frac32}+C=\frac19(6x+2)^{\frac32}+C$$, by using the power rule for derivatives and the chain rule.